# How to parse a C/C++ header file in dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm working on a flutter desktop app which should (according to my plan) has the ability to open C/C++ header files (as a plain text) and parse the source code and find all `structures` and get theirs properties, is there any existing package fits my need, or, maybe I should go with `regex` instead?

Comment: did you try dart:ffi ??

Comment: While regular expressions are usually to powerful to really need them, in this case (parsing C++) they are actually not powerful enough. C++ as a language is just to complicated to parse with regular expressions only. I recommend you try to find a library with Dart bindings for parsing (if one is available). Unfortunately asking for library recommendation isn't [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here.

Comment: I just want to parse the file as a plain text, the `ffi` package as far as know is for interoperability

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/antlr4